# spring mvc 3 caching example

Tags: spring, caching, spring-mvc

I have requirement for spring mvc 3 caching. Requirement is : while starting the server, we need to call database for one dropdown and put those values in the cache. So that whenever we required those values, we need to retrieve from cache.

Please help me with an example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can use init-method (Spring 2.5) or @PostConstruct annotation (in Spring 3.0).
This method will be called during server start up 
The following is code snippet

```
@Component
public class CacheDBData {

private String values[];
//add setter & getter

//This will be called during server start up after properties are initialised
@PostConstruct
public void getDataFromDB() {
values = //Logic to get data from DB and store that in values property
}
}
```

Suppose for example you can use in class as follows

```
@controller
public class HomeController {
@Autowired
private CacheDBData cacheDBData ;
//getter and setters
private void methodxyz() {
String values[] = cacheDBData.getValues();
}
}
```

Comment: you are correct, we need to use @PostConstruct which will be called at server start up. But this values will not be present in cache right? as mentioned in above method "methodxyz()", whenever we will call "cacheDBData.getValues();", again database hit will be happen right? I want to put those values in cache. please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with [Ehcahe for Spring](https://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/). There's a couple of config files to setup but after that you simply annotate the methods you want to cache the output from and it just works.

This has the advantage that you can change the values coming back from the service/database and NOT have to restart your app, unlike the accepted answer.